# Break decimal value into two values (before and after decimal)

Tags: c#

How to break a decimal value into integer values, first value should be the value before decimal and the other value of after decimal.

Problem : Decimal place is unknown as well as the number of digits;
ex :

```
double value = 2635.215;
int firstValue = 2635; // Should be
int secondValue = 215; // Should be
```

Comment: What *separates* the integer and decimal parts? Could it somehow be used as a delimiter?

Comment: Do you really want radically different results for "2635.215" and "2635.2150000001" which is a very similar number? It sounds like *at least* using `decimal` might be more appropriate than `double`... and there could be more fundamental problems with what you're trying to do. Please give more context.

Comment: @John Skeet Actually i'm developing an application in Silverlight, at some part i wanted to round up some figures but unfortunately C# inbuilt "maths.Round" giving wrong result. So in such case i decided to create of my own

Comment: @Faizan you have rounding options also `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` or `ToEven`, Did you try them /

Comment: Faizan, in the future keep in mind that it is better to post a question explaining what you are trying to achieve instead of asking us to help you implement the solution which you *think* is going to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: absolutely agree with @MikeNakis here. Also, even _if_ you really had to implement your own rounding function, going via strings seems like the worst way possible to do it

Comment: @MikeNakis Ya ill keep it in mind, well i thought asking the main problem is comfortable to all and explaining each and every thing make people confusing even it make people harder to understand it.

Comment: What results do you expect for `1.01` or `1.001`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.Split` method for splitting a string. Convert `double` to string and then split it based on `.`

Comment: So, what happens if value = 1.0/3.0;

Comment: not getting "based on ." it'll be better if u give some example.

Comment: @Faizan: Based on is not a method. Read about String.Split method. use `.` as a delimiter.

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution:

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace DecimalSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double value = 2635.215;
            var values = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
            int firstValue = int.Parse(values[0]);
            int secondValue = int.Parse(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when converting to String will ensure that the decimal separator will be a `.` and the split will be done in the right place. In my culture the decimal separator was a `,` for example

Comment: One up for taking Cultures into account.

Comment: I'm going to suggest this is the closest to being a safe, correct answer to the problem so far, but if we're going to take culture in to account then we might as well ensure safety and first and wrap the whole thing in `if (!value.IsNaN && !value.IsInfinity) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This problem is unsolvable, because a double value can have an extremely large number of decimal digits, so you cannot guarantee to be able to represent them in an integer.  The closest I can give you is this, which works not with integers, but with doubles:

```
double left = System.Math.Floor(value);
double right = left - value;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *decimal digits of a double value can be infinite* ?

Comment: I mean, try representing 1/3 in a double. Tell me how many decimal digits you get. And actually, the digits do not have to be infinite; if they are simply more than 10, there is no 32-bit integer that can represent them.

Comment: @MikeNakis double has *64-bit floating-point values*, 1/3 would be rounded to keep the value in those 64 bits. So "double value can be infinite" is confusing in terms of memory allocation. If you meant it in terms of math then you may need to rephrase your answer.

Comment: Yes, okay, you are right. That's a technicality, but I will correct my answer accordingly so as to be correct.

Comment: @V4 no it will not be infinite, have limitation 1KK

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
double decimalNumber = 123.456;
var numbersBeforeDecimalPoint = Math.Truncate(decimalNumber);
var numbersAfterDecimalPoint = decimalNumber - numbersBeforeDecimalPoint;
```

Using `Math.Truncate` we can get only the whole numbers, and we can then use that in tandem with our original number to get the decimal part.
This would give you `123` and `0.456` as a result.

Not sure if that's exactly what you're after (I appreciate you might want `123` and `456`) - there are lots of good suggestions here for string manipulations to do it if you need more specific formatting.

Comment: The whole idea is good and easy, but you have some several issues doing this with the math processor. Try it at fiddler and you will get 0.456000000000003. I think it needs more validations before get a definitive output

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little improvment of Răzvan Panda [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8725535/1735032).

An exception was raised in `int secondValue = int.Parse(values[1]);`  if we parse a value with no decimal.

Another point is that it's better to have a string for the second value. See, example 3.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double val1 = 2635.215;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetFirstValue(val1));     // out 2635
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetSecondValue(val1));    // out 215

    double val2 = 2;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetFirstValue(val2));     // out 2
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetSecondValue(val2));    // out ''

    double val3 = 3.04;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetFirstValue(val3));     // out 3
    Console.Out.WriteLine(GetSecondValue(val3));    // out 04
}

public static string GetFirstValue(double value)
{
    var values = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
    return values[0];
}

public static string GetSecondValue(double value)
{
    var values = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.');
    return values.Length > 1 ? values[1] : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    double value = 2635.215;
    string a = value.ToString();
    string[] b =a.Split('.');
    int firstValue= int.Parse(b[0]);
    int secondValue= int.Parse(b[1]);
```

Comment: So, what happens if `value = System.Math.PI`;

Comment: Question says "Decimal place is unknown as well as the number of digits". So, it could be 1000 digits of which 999 are to the right of the decimal point.